# facebook fql for retrieving photos returns empty list []

Tags: facebook-fql

```
select object_id, aid, src_small from photo where owner='{0}' ; {0}-the id of the user.
```

This query returns 0 records. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be an issue with permissions. You may need to grant user_photos permission.

See here - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions